# How to create a ranking using MySQL SUM

Tags: mysql

I'd like to create a ranking of views but I just receive one row, could anyone tell me how can I do it?

I tried the following:

```
SELECT userid, SUM(views) FROM earnings ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 7
```

And I got:

```
userid  |  SUM(views)
341     |  406756
```

And I'd like it:

```
userid | views
44     | 99999
33     | 88888
22     | 77777
11     | 66666
```

I really don't know how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this issue before many moons ago! What you want to do is harness [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) on the `userid`:

```
SELECT 
    userid, 
    SUM(views) 
FROM 
    earnings 
GROUP BY
    userid
ORDER BY 
    views 
DESC
LIMIT 7
```

Comment: @FernandoOliveira no worries mate!